# Why does T extends Comparable <? super T> include T? Meaning includes Comparable<T>?

Tags: java, super

```
class BinarySearch<T extends Comparable<? super T> >
```

Why is `T extends Comparable <? super T>` including `T`, meaning including `Comparable<T>` and not just the super class hierarchy? I am confused on the super keyword as I thought super would only include super class items. I am new to java and in the Java book it had the following example:

This is regarding a method in a class that was trying to limit the upper and lower bound of the hierarchy using the Java.awt.Component so the class had extends Container

```
class CustomComponent<T extends Container>
```

in the class they have the following method

```
void describeComponent<CustomComponent<? super JPasswordField> ref)
```

and then goes on to say

**Note that JPasswordField, which is a superclass of JTextField, itself is omitted in the list of permissible objects.**

Comment: The point of the above construct is so that if you have `class Animal implements Comparable<Animal>`, and `class Dog extends Animal`, the constraing will accept `Dog` which is comparable with all `Animal`s, even though it's not comparable with `Dog` specifically. That said, you do not want to **prevent** that - `? super T` is *not supposed to* mean "*only* superclasses of `T`", but "`T` or any of its superclasses".

Comment: Do you have a link to the documentation of that `describeComponent` method? It appears to be wrong (or perhaps garbled), but it's hard to tell without more context.

Comment: Java Programming
By: Poornachandra Sarang
Publisher: McGraw-Hill
Pub. Date: January 20, 2012
Print ISBN-13: 978-0-071-63360-4
E-Book ISBN-13: 978-0-071-63361-1
Pages in Print Edition: 672

Comment: Its in this section: Bounded Wildcards
So far, you have learned about the bounded types and wildcards. A bounded type sets the restriction on a type used by a generic to a certain class hierarchy. A wildcard allows you to substitute any of the allowed types in the generic parameter type. In some situations, you may want to set both the upper and lower bounds on the range of classes used in generics. As an example of this, look at the class hierarchy in Figure 12-1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [Lower Bounded Wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/lowerBounded.html), a section of the [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) section of *The Java Tutorial*:

> ... a *lower bounded* wildcard restricts the unknown type to be **a specific type or a *super type* of that type.**

<sup>(bold mine, emphasis theirs)</sup>

Thus, the set of classes that match `T extends Comparable<T>` is a *subset* of the set of classes that match `T extends Comparable<? super T>`. The wildcard `? super T` itself matches `T` and any superclasses of `T`.

In other words, the assumption that "`super` would only include super class items" is simply incorrect.

Your confusion in the example may also arise from the fact that `JTextField` is a *superclass* of `JPasswordField`; in other words, `JPasswordField extends JTextField`. The example would match any of the following classes:

- javax.swing.JPasswordField
- javax.swing.JTextField
- javax.swing.JTextComponent
- javax.swing.JComponent
- java.awt.Container
- java.awt.Component
- java.lang.Object

The example would make much more sense as the following:

> ```
> void describeComponent(CustomComponent<? super JTextField> ref) {...}
> ```
>
> Note that JPasswordField, which is a subclass of JTextField, itself is
>   omitted in the list of permissible objects, because it is not a
>   superclass of JTextField.

Comment: This makes sense so in your example JTextField is included but not JPasswordField since it extends JTextField.  That makes much more sense thanks for clarifying. I think it was unclear their definition of "super" this seems much more logical.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the semantic meaning of "<T extends Comparable<? super T> >"
is that either T or a superclass of T must implement Comparable