# Quick Sort practice using Java

Tags: java, quicksort

This is my first attempt at Quick Sort using Java and I am also looking for some helpful criticisms on how I can make my code better for displaying the list for Hoare. Is there something specific I need to add in order to display the result?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Quicksort<E extends Comparable<E>> {
    
    // Quicksort using Hoare's partition
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quicksortHoare(ArrayList<E> list, int l, int r) {
        // Sorting the given ArrayList (of generic type E) in descending order      
        if (l < r) {
            int pivot = partitionHoare(list, l, r);
            quicksortHoare(list, l, pivot);
            quicksortHoare(list, pivot + 1, r);
        }                   
    }   
    
    // Hoare's partition (always select the first element as the pivot)
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partitionHoare(ArrayList<E> list, int l, int r) {
        E pivot = list.get(l);
        int i = l - 1;
        int j = r + 1;

        while (true) {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) > 0);

            do {
                j--;
            } while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) < 0);

            if (i >= j) {
                return j;
            }

            E temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(j));
            list.set(j, temp);
        }
                                
    }

    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test1 = {3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6, 9};  

        //  Printed the list
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int num : test1) {
            list1.add(num);
        }
        System.out.println("*** Test 1 ***");
        System.out.println("Original list: " + list1);
        System.out.println("Hoare's quicksort: " + test1);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: "*...  I am also looking for some helpful criticisms on how I can make my code better ....*"  - We do not do code review here. For this, you may want to post the (working!) code to [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I tried there but they referred me to here.

Comment: most probably because the code is not working as expected. Code review only accepts working code.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of the QuickSort algorithm using Hoare's partition scheme looks good. However, in order to display the sorted list using Hoare's quicksort, you need to actually call the `quicksortHoare()` method with the appropriate parameters and then print the sorted list.

Here's an updated version of your code with the necessary changes.
In this updated code, we call the `quicksortHoare()` method passing the `list1`, start index `0`, and end index `list1.size() - 1`. After sorting the list, we print the sorted list using: `System.out.println("Hoare's quicksort: " + list1);`

Now, when you run the program, it will display the original list and the sorted list using Hoare's quicksort algorithm.

Here is the code version of the above explanation:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Quicksort<E extends Comparable<E>> {

    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> void quicksortHoare(ArrayList<E> list, int l, int r) {
        if (l < r) {
            int pivot = partitionHoare(list, l, r);
            quicksortHoare(list, l, pivot);
            quicksortHoare(list, pivot + 1, r);
        }
    }

    // Hoare's partition (always select the first element as the pivot)
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>> int partitionHoare(ArrayList<E> list, int l, int r) {
        E pivot = list.get(l);
        int i = l - 1;
        int j = r + 1;

        while (true) {
            do {
                i++;
            } while (list.get(i).compareTo(pivot) < 0);

            do {
                j--;
            } while (list.get(j).compareTo(pivot) > 0);

            if (i >= j) {
                return j;
            }

            E temp = list.get(i);
            list.set(i, list.get(j));
            list.set(j, temp);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] test1 = {3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6, 9};

        // Convert the array to ArrayList
        ArrayList<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int num : test1) {
            list1.add(num);
        }

        System.out.println("*** Test 1 ***");
        System.out.println("Original list: " + list1);

        // Sort the list using Hoare's quicksort
        quicksortHoare(list1, 0, list1.size() - 1);

        System.out.println("Hoare's quicksort: " + list1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to get it right, I appreciated it really. I thought I was supposed to use test to call the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

To print your array as readable text, you can use the *[Arrays.toString](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D))* method.

```java
System.out.println("Hoare's quicksort: " + Arrays.toString(test1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a requirement to use an array, it would simplify the code a bit to use a `List` which is also easier to display.

- use `List.of()` to create an immutable list of the items.
- then pass that as an argument to `new ArrayList<>()` to create a mutable list for sorting.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>(List.of(3, 5, 2, 4, 1, 8, 7, 6, 9));
        System.out.println("*** Test 1 ***");
        System.out.println("Original list: " + list1);
        quicksortHoare(list1, list1.size() - 1);
        System.out.println("Hoare's quicksort: " + list1);
    }
```

Note that in your main routines, it is considered best practice to pass implemented interfaces to their interface type.  So for the first argument to `quicksortHoare` and `partitionHoare`, use `List<E> list` instead of `ArrayList<E> list`.  This will allow your methods to accept any type of list that implements the `List` interface.

Since your methods are static, there is no need to declare your main class as generic.  Just use `<E extends Comparable<? super E>>` as the accepted type on each method.  Rather than explain the purpose of that declaration here, just check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18163670/why-does-t-extends-comparable-super-t-include-t-meaning-includes-comparable) on stackoverflow.

And finally, there is nothing wrong with your `do/while loops`.  But you can also use just `while loops` as follows.  Notice the `prefix increment/decrement` **before** using the indices.

```
 while (list.get(++i).compareTo(pivot) < 0);
 while (list.get(--j).compareTo(pivot) > 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class QuickLomuto{
public void quickSort(int a[], int p, int r) {

    /*
    p -> low
    r -> high
    q -> pivot
    */
    if(p < r) {
        int q = partition(a, p, r);
        quickSort(a, p, q-1);
        quickSort(a, q+1, r);
    }
}

public int partition(int a[], int p, int r) {

    /*
    p -> low
    r -> high
    x -> pivot
    */
    int x= a[r];  //(1) ...pivot = a[high]
    int i= p-1;   //(2) ...range  i -> a[i] < x

    for(int j=p; j<r; j++) {

        if(a[j] <= x) {
            i++;
            swap(a, i, j);  //...since (2) ...j should be in range(i, p)
        }
    }
    
    // swap (a[i+1], a[r])   
    //... put x i.e. 'pivot' in the correct position  ... since (1)
    
    swap(a, (i+1), r);  //(3) ... (i+1) -> pivot's correct place
    return i+1;
}

public int[] swap(int[] array, int x, int  y){
    int temp = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = temp;
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a[] = {100, 10, 5, 20, 80, 30, 70, 50, 15, 90, 40, 60, 9};
    
    int n = a.length;
    int low = 0;
    int high = n - 1;

    QuickLomuto lomuto = new QuickLomuto();
    lomuto.quickSort(a, low, high);

    System.out.println("quick sort with Lomuto partitioning");

    for(int x : a){
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Quick Sort in Java using Lomuto partitioning